# iPad's with flex - Height

Tags: ios, css, ipad, flexbox, height

Basically I have got a row with 3 columns, and the columns haves an image and text.

In chrome, Android, Fire-Fox, I managed to get each column the height of the parent, and then put the text in the middle if any other column is bigger. But in iPad with iOS 8.3 and 9.3.5, doesn't makes the columns big at 100% of the height.

The codepen is: https://codepen.io/rocketraccoon/pen/PEopPO

And here I leave the Snippet:

```css
body {
  background-color: red !important; /* Only for trying to see the visual effect required */
}

.triple-opcion {
  padding: 40px;
}

.triple-opcion .opciones .opcion {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 40px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.triple-opcion .opciones .opcion:hover,
.triple-opcion .opciones .opcion:focus,
.triple-opcion .opciones .opcion:active {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.triple-opcion .opciones .opcion .t5 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #191D22;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.triple-opcion .opciones .opcion img {
  width: 64px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="triple-opcion ayuda">
  <div class="row opciones opciones-ayuda">
    <div class="col-4">
      <a href="#>
        <div class="opcion">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="">
          <p class="t5">Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="opcion">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="">
          <p class="t5">24 months</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="opcion">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="">
          <p class="t5">48 months</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help you can provide will be helpful.

Comment: I know, that IE has problems with align-items when there is a min-height used: https://caniuse.com/#search=align-items probably here too?

Comment: @MrBuggy Looks like Safari doesn't supports `min-height`, but that's why I also included an `height` attribute. All devices working fine (IE haven't tested it yet) except Safari.

Comment: What happens if you remove the min-height?

Comment: I have updated the html. Even IE10 and IE11 can render it properly. And if I remove the min-height, nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using a `table`. I also took the opportunity to optimize your code. You should not be using block elements, eg `div`s inside anchor tags.

HTML:

```
<div class="triple-opcion ayuda">
  <div class="row opciones opciones-ayuda">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 opcion">
      <a class="inner">  
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="Buscador de números">
        <span class="t5">Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500
       </span>
      </a>
    </div>        
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 opcion">
      <a class="inner">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="Preguntas frecuentes">
        <span class="t5">24 months</span>
      </a>
    </div>       
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 opcion">
      <a class="inner">     
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="Sugerencias">
        <span class="t5">48 months</span>
      </a>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
body {
  background-color: red;
}
.triple-opcion {
  .opciones {
     display:table;
     table-layout:fixed;
     width:100%;
     border-spacing: 40px;
     border-collapse: separate;

    .opcion {
      text-align: center;
      padding: 40px;
      display: table-cell;
      height: 100%;
      background:#fff;
      vertical-align:middle;

      span {
        display:block;
      }

      &:hover,
      &:focus,
      &:active {
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      img {
        width: 64px;
      }
      .t5 {
        text-align: center;
        margin: auto;
        max-width: 100%;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a working pen - https://codepen.io/scooterlord/pen/NXWmQJ
It's too late and I am writing from my couch so I didn't test it on my iPad, but am fairly certain it works.

**Edit 2**: I just realized what was requested, the initial description of the issue was not very clear. Here is a new codepen with what is requested:

https://codepen.io/scooterlord/pen/eymprK

[image: iPad screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions about the div inside an anchor. Also thanks for the suggestion of using a table layout, but with the code providen it doesn't does what it has to do, as it does with the actual code (image always on top, and the text always centered).

Comment: @Cheshire check my answer for screenshot.

Comment: It can be a work around. Thanks for your time and wise =) Although I wished it could be done with flex =(

Comment: You are welcome, thanks for accepting my reply as an answer. Added bonus: I don't feel that flexbox has matured enough to be used yet. Most flexbox features can be replicated using tables, unless there is wrapping involved. A little more markup, but the result is guaranteed to be compatible with most (if not all) devices.